# How to add the name of a blog post's category to route url with Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, friendly-id

I have been trying to add the `name` of the `BlogCategory` that a `BlogPost` belongs to in a URL such as this:

`sitename.com/blog/category-name/blog-post-title`

At the very least, I want this to render for the `show` of the `BlogPost` but am okay with it being the url for every action such as `new`, `edit`, and `destroy`.

I'm using the `friendly_id` gem, if that makes a difference.

BlogCategory Model:

```
class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :blog_posts

  # This is a self referential relation. This is where records in a table may point to other records in the same table.
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "BlogCategory", foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :sub_category_blog_posts, through: :sub_categories, source: :blog_posts
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'BlogCategory', foreign_key: :parent_id, optional: true
  # This is a scope to load the top level categories and eager-load their posts, subcategories, and the subcategories' posts too.
  scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :blog_posts, sub_categories: :blog_posts }

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.nil? || name_changed?
  end
  
end
```

BlogCategory Controller:

```
class BlogCategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :admin_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_blog_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...

  private

  def cat_params
    params.require(:blog_category).permit(:name, :parent_id, :sub_category, :summary)
  end

  def main_cat
    @cat = BlogCategory.parent_id.nil?
  end

  def set_blog_link
    @blog_link = BlogCategory.friendly.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to action: action_name, id: @blog_link.friendly_id, status: 301 unless @blog_link.friendly_id == params[:id]
  end

end
```

BlogPost Model:

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :history
  belongs_to :blog_category
  validates  :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates  :summary, uniqueness: true
  default_scope {order(created_at: :desc)}

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.nil? || title_changed?
  end
end
```

BlogPost Controller:

```
class BlogPostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :admin_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_post_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :find_post, only: :show

  ...

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:blog_post).permit(:title, :body, :summary, :thumbnail_link, :blog_category_id)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = BlogPost.friendly.find(params[:id])

    # If an old id or a numeric id was used to find the record, then
    # the request path will not match the post_path, and we should do
    # a 301 redirect that uses the current friendly id.
    if request.path != blog_post_path(@post)
      return redirect_to @post, :status => :moved_permanently
    end
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def set_post_link
    @post_link = BlogPost.friendly.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to action: action_name, id: @post_link.friendly_id, status: 301 unless @post_link.friendly_id == params[:id]
    end

end
```

Here is relevant code from my `routes.rb file`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :blog_categories, path: 'blog'
  resources :blog_posts

end
```

---

### What I've tried

I've tried the following without success but have little understanding of what I'm doing:

```
get 'blog/:blog_category_name/:blog_post_title', to: 'blog_posts#show', as: 'blog_post'
```

and also tried

```
resources :blog_posts, path: 'blog/:blog_category_name/:blog_post_title', except: [:new, :create]
resources :blog_posts, only: [:new, :create]
```

With this in my `BlogPost` controller inside the `show` method/block:

```
@post_url = BlogPost.find_by(title: params[:blog_post_title], blog_category_id: params[:blog_category_name])
```

I even tried adding the params used in the routes to the permitted list under `post_params`.

I also tried making a new post to see if old posts weren't linking properly because of the url structure change.

The URL's I'm getting are not utilizing the parameters I'm passing to them.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is really just a [nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) but with a vanity route and and slugging which doesn't actually require such a heavy hand.

The typical controller for a nested resource would look like this:

```
class BlogPostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog_category
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :delete]

  # GET /blog/foo/bar  - your custom vanity route
  # the conventional route would be 
  # GET /blog_categories/foo/blog_posts/bar
  def show
  end

  # GET  /blog/foo/blogs_posts     -> index
  # GET  /blog/foo/blogs_posts/new -> new
  # POST /blog/foo/blogs_posts    -> create

  # ...  

  private

  def set_blog_category
    @blog_category = BlogCategory.friendly.find(params[:blog_category_id])
  end

  def set_blog
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Besides the fact that you're using `friendly.find` you don't actually need to do anything to do the lookup via slugs instead of the id column. If you want to find the records only by their friendly id (and not allow numerical ids) use the `find_by_friendly_id` method instead.

Note that `:id` (or `_id`) in a parameter name is not equal to the id column - it's just a name for the unique indentifier segment in the URI pattern.

While you can configure the name of the param its actually kind of silly as in Rails things just work when you stick with the conventions.

You can just define the vanity route for this as:

```erb
resources :blog_categories, path: 'blog', only: [] do
  # the typical routes nested under "blog_posts"
  resources :blogs_posts, only: [:new, :create] 
  # your custom vanity route should be defined last to avoid conflicts
  resources :blogs_posts, path: '/', only: :show
end
```

Generating the URL can be done either by calling the named `blog_category_blog_path` helper or by using the polymorphic route helpers:

```erb
blog_category_blog_path(@blog_category, @blog_post) 
redirect_to [@blog_category, @blog_post]
form_with model: [@blog_category, @blog_post]
```

If you have legacy URLs using a different structure that you want to redirect I would consider using a separate controller or just doing the redirect in the routes to separate out the responsibilities from this controller.

You also should avoid duplicating the authorization/authentication logic across your controllers (your `admin_user` method). Thats how you get security holes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll test this out when I can. As the aside, are you saying the `admin_user` should be consolidated to something like the `sessions` helper? Also I was just trying the "legacy" fixes with the notion that their urls would physically change because of the new urls I was calling them by. - probably wrong?

Comment: "As the aside, are you saying the admin_user should be consolidated to something like the sessions helper?"  Yes, but don't mix up authorization (who can do what) and authentication (who is who).  Typically you would use a separate component such as Pundit or CanCanCan to define and enforce the authorization rules.

Comment: "Also I was just trying the "legacy" fixes with the notion that their urls would physically change because of the new urls I was calling them by.". Not really. What you can do is redirect and use as "301 - Moved Permanently" instead of the default 302 which tells the client (seach as search engine crawlers) to use the new URL instead.

Comment: @Jake I can't follow the exact steps that you're taking here so you're going to have to take the theoretical underpinnings here and apply them to your use case. Its impossible to hand hold via comments - so if needed ask a new question instead.

Comment: Great, I figured it out! I just had to change the route you mentioned to `blog_posts` from the plural you gave; the route in my `find_post` method to the one you supplied; and `Blog` in the `set_blog` method to `BlogPost`.

Comment: Okay, finally have everything sorted, I also had to change my `before_action :set_blog_category` to be only for `:show` and also had to replace my update method's `redirect_to` to use the route helper you mentioned. I had to keep my old route helper for links to and on my edit and delete pages for these posts.